# AWS SNS filtered subscription with exists = false for messages without attributes set

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am setting up subscriptions to a topic that a number of different apps publish to. I want to filter the subscription of one particular app so that it doesn't receive back messages that it sends.

I tried adding an attribute with a value identifying the app, eg `x-forwarded-by=myapp` and set the filter policy as:

```
{
  "x-forwarded-by": [{"anything-but": ["myapp"]}]
}
```

That correctly prevented the app receiving these however it also didn't receive any messages where there was no `x-forwarded-by` attribute, nor did it receive any messages whether there were either no attributes or there was an empty attribute object, eg, I would have expected to see messages with:

```
"MessageAttributes": null
"MessageAttributes": {}
"MessageAttributes": {"someOtherAttribute":{"DataType":"string", "StringValue": "SomeValue"}}
```

I also tried using an `exists` filter so that if the app set that attribute, it could filter it out later, eg:

```
{
  "x-forwarded-by-my-app": [{"exists":false}]
}
```

This only worked if there was at least one other attribute set, and this would require me updating every app that publishes to include a dummy attribute.

I tried combining them, as in:

```
{
  "x-forwarded-by": [
    {"exists":false},
    {"anything-but":["myapp"]}
}
```

And this worked *slightly* better as it handled the case of the `x-forwarded-by` header either not being present or having a different value. It doesn't however handle the case of no attributes being set.

Is there a way to achieve this with a filtered subscription or do I have to just have the app receive these notifications and have the app check for and ignore them?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some issue with "anything-but", I tried this with { {"exists":false},"anything-but":["myapp", ""]} and it works.
In my case I went ahead with: {{"exists":false},"positiveCase"}.

Comment: That still doesn't work for the case where a message was sent without any attributes. A few months ago AWS released Lambda event filtering which looks like it can more flexibly handle this. I'm going to try that out and see if it works for my scenario https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html